# How do I take a populated JSON and then input it into PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a script that produces a JSON-formatted response from a third party website and displays it on the users page. Instead of this, I want the script to post the response to a PHP page so that I can save it in the backend of my website. Below is an example of the code I am currently using that displays the response on the page. I don't know how to make it so the response can then be used as an input for a form.

```
<form action=here.php method=post>
    <?PHP
$token=$_POST['token'];
echo '<input id="token" type="hidden" name="token" value=' . $token . '>';
?>
        <script>
        function pay() {
            var token = document.getElementById('token').value;
            var paymentData = {
                ssl_txn_auth_token: token,
            };
            var callback = {
                onApproval: function (response) {
                    console.log("Approval Code=" + response['ssl_approval_code']);
                    showResult("approval", JSON.stringify(response));
                }
            };
            ConvergeEmbeddedPayment.pay(paymentData, callback);
            return false;
        }

        function showResult(status, msg) {
            document.getElementById('txn_status').innerHTML = "
            <b>" + status + "</b>";
            document.getElementById('txn_response').innerHTML = msg;
        }
    window.onload = pay();
    
        </script>
    </form>

        Transaction Status:
    <div id="txn_status"></div>

        Transaction Response:
    <div id="txn_response"></div>
```

What I want this to do is the data that displays on the users page where `"<div id="txn_status"></div>"` and `"<div id="txn_response"></div>"`, I want that data to become values I can use on input forms `<input type=hidden id=status value=<div id="txn_status"></div> />` and `<input type=hidden id=response value=<div id="txn_response"></div> />` but of course, I don't want the values to be the code, I want them to be the data that is created by the script when the page loads

Comment: Side note: You should wrap that `' . $token . '` in `htmlspecialchars()` to prevent some xss attack vectors.

Comment: If I understand well, you can use a JavaScript code to add dynamic hidden fields to the form like presented here: http://jsfiddle.net/s55snxtn/ Is it a solution for your problem?

Comment: The $token variable is generated by my own script. Should I worry about attack vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the JSON in the value of the hidden input in the function that displays the response.

```
        function showResult(status, msg) {
            document.getElementById('txn_status').innerHTML = "<b>" + status + "</b>";
            document.getElementById('txn_response').innerHTML = msg;
            document.getElementById('response').value = msg;
            document.getElementById('status').value = status;
        }
```

Another problem with your code:

```
window.onload = pay();
```

should be

```
window.onload = pay;
```

The value of an `onXXX` property must be a function to call when the event occurs, your code calls the function during the assignment.

The full corrected code:

```
<script>
function pay() {
    var token = document.getElementById('token').value;
    var paymentData = {
        ssl_txn_auth_token: token,
    };
    var callback = {
        onApproval: function (response) {
            console.log("Approval Code=" + response['ssl_approval_code']);
            showResult("approval", JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    };
    ConvergeEmbeddedPayment.pay(paymentData, callback);
    return false;
}

function showResult(status, msg) {
    document.getElementById('txn_status').innerHTML = "<b>" + status + "</b>";
    document.getElementById('txn_response').innerHTML = msg;
    document.getElementById('response').value = msg;
    document.getElementById('status').value = status;
}
window.onload = pay();

</script>
```

Comment: So this doesn't work. When looking at the output after, it just contains the text of the code, it doesn't show the response the code is supposed to make

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. It clearly should be putting the same text in the input values as it puts into the DIV contents.

Comment: My answer was that you should simply replace your definition of `showResult` with mine, leave everything else the same. So if the old code was working to fill in the DIV, the new code should fill in the DIV and hidden inputs.

Comment: It's hard to read code in comments. What's the difference between what you wrote and what I wrote in my answer?

Comment: You don't put function definitions inside `<input>` elements. The function goes in the `<script>` block where you already have it.[

Comment: I'm assuming you were saying to have this as the code:

<input type="hidden" value="function showResult(status, msg)......
        }" />

I have that sending to an email and when I receive the email, all I get is the code rather than what the results of the script would be. So the email says "function showResult..." rather than showing "{"data1":"answer1", "data2":answer2, "}"

Comment: You assumed wrong. The value is filled in by the `showResult()` function when it's called from the callback function.

Comment: Don't you understand what `document.getElementById('response').value = msg;` does?

Comment: JavaScript isn't executed inside `value` attributes.

Comment: I apologize, I don't understand what document.getElementById('response').value = msg; does. But I understand what you were saying about where to put that code, but how do I get that value into an input on a form?

Comment: That's what puts it into the value of the input. The input should have `id="response"`, and that fills it in, just like assigning to `innerHTML` fills in the HTML of a DIV.

Comment: OH! God, I'm thick. I get it now. Thank you so much